# Forking a process with C

Tags: c, fork

I'm following [this guide](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html) about `fork()` but something isn't clear for me.

> Both processes will start their execution at the next statement following the fork() call. In this case, both processes will start their execution at the assignment statement as shown below:
>   [image]

According to this sentence, this script

```
printf("before ");
fork();
printf("after ");
```

should print this: (Because child process will start from `printf("after")`)

```
before after after
```

but it is printing this instead:

```
before after before after
```

So did the child process start from the 1st line of the file? Can you tell me what's wrong with my code? Did I misunderstood that sentence?

**EDIT**

Script compiled and executed on OS X

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a new process, it 'inherits' all the variables of the original process - thus all the buffers as well. Since "before" wasn't flushed yet and is still in the buffer, the child process will as well contain this string in the buffer and print it. Therefore you have to call `fflush(stdout);` before forking the process.

Comment: Are they using same buffer? Or child process just 'inheriting' buffer from parent and creating a buffer for itself?

Comment: It has it's own buffer, but the buffer will contain the same value as the parent's buffer had at the time of forking. If you for example create the variable `int i = 10;`, then the child will have the variable `i` with the value 10 (until you overwrite it). But they are both still different variables, they just happen to contain the same value at the time of forking.

Comment: I want to choose this as *Accepted Answer* because you sent answer first. But I'm recommending everyone who experience same problem with me, should also read Ed Heal, b4hand and user3386109's answers.

It's really difficult to choose one of these answers.

Comment: I would say that `fork` operates at the memory level and thus describing it as "inheriting variables" is a bit misleading. It's better to think of the entire memory space as being cloned even though in practice the memory is shared until written to by one of the processes.

Answer (score 3):

You understood the sentence correctly, but...

When you call `fork` it takes a snapshot of the process, and creates an exact duplicate. So if there is data buffered in `stdout` waiting to be written to the console, then that data will be in the child's output buffer after the fork, as well as the parent's buffer.

There are two ways to clear the output buffer before the fork. You can either add a newline `\n` at the end of the `printf`

```
printf( "before\n" );
fork();
printf( "after\n" );
```

or you can use the `fflush` function

```
printf( "before " );
fflush( stdout );
fork();
printf( "after " );
```

Comment: Great. Now I have 4 great answers, and I have to choose one of them as *Accepted Answer* .

Comment: Actually your answer's format was better. And it's really difficult to make a fair decision.

Comment: @Eray Don't worry about it. I've been in the same situation when I've asked questions on other forums, so I know what it's like. You made a good decision :)

Answer (score 2):

It is because the "before" is buffered and only outputted when that buffer is flushed. This occurs in when the two processes terminates.

Comment: So, actually my problem isn't about forking, is about 'printing' , right? Which function / method should I use to print something to screen without buffering?

Comment: And one more question. Child process don't know anything about `printf("before")` and there is no "before" string in child process buffer. So why it's also printing "before" string when child process terminated.

Comment: Well, @Philipp Murry just explaned answer of my last question.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `fflush` on `stdout` prior to `fork`, you will see the output you expect. In general, C buffered IO won't play nicely when you do operations at the OS level.

The memory buffer associated with the standard output is cloned on `fork` including any previously buffered output. That's why you see the "before" twice.